# Starting Ubuntu without the GUI

Tags: ubuntu, gui, xfce

I want to boot a "Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS" server, but I want XFCE *not* to be started, nor X at all, only Shell.

How do I tell my server to boot to the shell, not running XFCE at all?

I have an SSH connection to the server, but no display connected.

Since I migrated from earlier versions I use GRUB 1, where no /etc/default/grub exists.

I would like to set the target runlevel somewhere, without changing GRUB at all.

Comment: When you ssh into the machine, don',t put the "X" flag. example "ssh username@localhost.edu"

Comment: In the meantime I found "sudo service gdm stop" and "sudo service gdm start" which goes to the right direction. But "gdm stop" should be the default. Or I install Ubuntu server. But then I cant change any more. A link was: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305659

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see three ways to do it:

**1. Changing the default runlevel**

You can set it at the beginnign of `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` replace 2 by 3 and reboot.
You can enable the graphical interface with `telinit 2`.([More about runlevels](http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html))

**2. Do not launch the graphical interface service on boot**

`update-rc.d -f xdm remove`

Quick and easy. You can re-enable the graphical interface with `service xdm start` or revert your changes with `update-rc.d -f xdm defaults`

**3. Remove packages**

`apt-get remove --purge x11-common && apt-get autoremove`

I think it suits best for a computer considered as a server.
You can re-enable the graphical interface by reinstalling the packages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much. Changing the default runlevel: I edited /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf and have set the default runlevel to 3 (instead of 2). But Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS seems to ignore this.

Comment: Have you looked if `/etc/inittab` exists on your system?

Comment: No that etc/inittab is missing on Ubuntu

Comment: what does the `runlevel`command say?

Comment: If the file `/etc/rc3.d/S??xdm` exists, then remove it.

Comment: runlevel says "N 2"   and an /etc/rc3.d/S??xdm alike file does not exist.

Comment: Are your sure the `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` is edited correctly? You should have the line `env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=3` (with 3 instead of 2).

Answer (score 11):

I got a simple method to disable XFCE from this blog post:
[How to disable X at boot time in Ubuntu 11.10](https://nunomgsantos.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time-in-ubuntu-11-10). 
Note: the post has a heading in some non-English language,
possibly Portuguese, but the body of the post is in English.

With LightDM (`lightdm`) being the new graphical user login in Ubuntu,
users will need to find a way to disable it to boot into text mode. 
Fortunately, the people behind LightDM have made that really easy to do.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite editor,

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="<doesn’t matter what you find here>"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

No need to remove / disable LightDM upstart conf;
it already does that for you.

lightdm.conf

```
# Check kernel command-line for inhibitors, unless we are being called manually.
for ARG in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
        if [ "$ARG" = "text" ]; then
                plymouth quit || :
                stop
                exit 0
        fi
done
```

You will still be able to use X by typing `startx` after you logged in.

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04 you have to disable lightdm manually. see: http://askubuntu.com/a/694718/299538

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04, use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="3"`.  See https://superuser.com/a/1139020/391956