# Boot Ubuntu 16.04 into command line / do not start GUI

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, gui, ubuntu-16.04

I want my Ubuntu 16.04 to not start GUI on boot and show command line console only. I have tried the following recipies but none of them are for version 16.04 and so they do not seem to work — GUI starts anyway:

1. [GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/)
2. [Changing the default runlevel](https://superuser.com/questions/310978/starting-ubuntu-without-the-gui)

Ideally I also want to be able to start GUI by typig a command.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could disable the display manager service with `systemctl`.  For example if your display manager is `lightdm` then run:

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

This will prevent the service from starting at boot.

**Edit**:

I forgot to mention how to start the GUI. It is as simple as starting the systemd service:

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm.service
```

Comment: This worked for me on 16.04 on a arm board. Thanks. :)

Comment: This did not work on my system.  (16.04 LTS on a PC)  It shows the initial screen with all the [ OK ] messages as the services start, and then freezes.

Comment: BTW to re-enable the service the command is actually sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service

Answer (score 25):

Instead of `text` use runlevel `3`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="3"

# To remove all the fancy graphics you need to get rid of `splash`.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet”

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only) 
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Then `update-grub` and reboot.

---

But you really only need `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="3"`. For quick test hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> during booting to get into the grub boot menu. Then press <kbd>e</kbd> and find the line which specifies *kernel* and add `3` at the end:

```
 linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu ro 3
```

Boot it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

---

> Ideally I also want to be able to start GUI by typig a command.

One of these:

```
$ sudo telinit 5
$ sudo service lightdm restart
$ sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Replacing "text" by "3", worked for me ! Very efficient ! Thanks

Comment: hi. the answer looks nice but its hard to understand. I just Ideally need one command to boot into text mode, do what I need, and go back into normal desktop mode.

Comment: @nyxee My answer has 3 sections. Follow the second: "For quick test hit..."

Comment: I appreciate the information in your post. by the time people look for this information, they are normally exhausted with other options. I gave an example of a simple answer below.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm just used to post longer answers with a lot of information so we all can learn more. And also I'm familiar with grub cmd line options so it's faster for me to add *3* and I'm good to go + it's multi-distro solution :)

Comment: I'm still looking at it to understand whats going on. When i'm done with the unity issues i'll be back . just had to uninstall ubuntu-desktop and unity (the original cause of my problems)

Comment: great answer, which file contain the "linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu ro 3" command ?

Comment: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but this file is generated so you should be doing changes in `/etc/default/grub` instead.

Comment: Worked for me on `Xubuntu 18.04`.

Answer (score 12):

- When in GUI-mode, this will take you to text-mode (runlevel 2,3,4) on reboot. You may get a blank screen (no-gui) which is a reminder that there's no GUI :-), enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>(<kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd>,...) to use the runlevels.

`systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

- This will take you back to GUI boot when you are in text-mode.

`systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Answer (score 9):

One of the following, as part of the kernel command line (editable via GRUB), should work:

- `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` will override the default of "graphical.target" – this, along with *systemctl set-default*, is the equivalent of "default runlevel";
- `systemd.mask=lightdm.service` will forbid a specific service from starting, until manually *systemctl unmask*'d later;
- `systemd.mask=display-manager.service` – same;
- `rescue` aka `systemd.unit=rescue.target` is the equivalent of "single-user runlevel"; not for daily use, but useful when fixing broken GUI.

Comment: it would be useful to mention how you *return to normality* from that "emergency setting" .

Comment: For the benefit of others, the actual CLI command you want is `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` (and I believe `systemctl set-default graphical.target` would reset it)

Comment: That's only if you want it semi-permanent, and can reach a shell in the first place. The main post has nothing to do with CLI commands.

Answer (score 4):

for ubuntu 18.04 enable root user

```
 sudo passwd
```

and then

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```